# What are all of the firing range sequences?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

Screwing around on the firing range in Call of Duty WWII, I triggered something and watermelons came tumbling out from the side of the range, and I got a message saying that I completed a sequence. How do I recreate this, and are there other known sequences?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There appears to be three sequences. One is the watermelons, one is some explosions, and the last and hardest one has some fireworks. Upon completing all the sequences, you'll earn a calling card (and experience for each sequence).  The below video shows how to do all three sequences.  Note that you may need some help from other players or friends in order to shoot enough/all targets.

**Sequence One**: On the right side of the course are two diamond shaped targets, each on their own wooden stand. Shoot them, and three targets drop down from the wooden stand.  Shoot the three targets that drop down from both stands.  After shooting those, five targets appear on a wall on the right and three targets appear on a wall on the back right.  Shoot all of these targets. After that, two soldier targets appear.  Shoot the soldier targets, and the watermelons are thrown onto the course.

**Sequence Two**: Start by shooting targets that are on the sniper tower  on the right side of the range. There are 6 targets on it.  Shoot them, and 2 soldiers targets appear on the top of the tower.  Shoot them, and 3 moving targets will appear in the back middle of the range.  **One is a civilian target, which you do not want to shoot** (you can tell the difference based on if the target has a hat or helmet on.  The hat wearing target is the civilian).  Take out the other two targets, and you complete the sequence.

**Sequence Three**:  In the middle of the firing range are some soldier targets.  Destroy them, and more will appear further back. Destroy these, and more will appear even further back.  Destroy these, and a single soldier target will be in the middle of range in the back.  Shoot this soldier target, and a single disc target will be thrown into the air.  Shoot the disc, and two more discs will be thrown at the same time.  Shoot these two discs, and three more will be thrown.  Shoot these three, and the sequence will be complete.

Comment: "One is the watermelons, one is some explosions, and the last and hardest one grants a calling card and experience" completing all 3 gives the calling card not just the last one

Comment: Sequence three is extremely hard without more help.  I can only shoot the first flying disc and fail on the two discs.  Can't imagine 3.

Comment: The idea is to do it with friends, try using LFG for someone.